# Eclipse: how to distinguish between public comments and private comments in my code?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, comments, subversive

I'm looking for a systematic way how to have in my eclipse projects' code, private comments (which I do not want other team members to see when they check out my code), as well as public comments (which I do want to share with others); a way that will allow me to only commit to svn the code with comments I want to make public?

I use eclipse subversive.

Comment: This is a request on SVN, not on Eclipse. SVN support comments on commits, but doesn't seem to support a feature like private or public comments or an other policy on comments.

Comment: This sounds like a nightmare. What happens when another team member edits the file, then you retrieve her changes?

Comment: @Dale Wilson I would be asked to merge their code with mine. But theirs will only include public comments.

Comment: And if they happen to delete or significantly alter the section of code where you have your "private" comments you are expecting subversion to somehow successfully merge this?  As I said -- a nightmare.  Find another way to solve our problem.  @vkg's answer is a good one.

Comment: @Dale Wilson I am looking for something that would at least let me associate the private comment with a specific source file. If not a specific position within a source file. Any ideas....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create files with the same base name, but the extension .notes.  Thus the class named Plover would be declared in Plover.hpp, defined in Plover.cpp and your private notes would be in Plover.notes.

You can then tell SVN not to check in your notes file using a command like:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "*.notes"
```

Comment: Good idea... thanks! And... it would have been close to perfect if I knew how I could sync all those file names in case I renamed the source file....

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing called private comments and public comments. Any thing you commit will be seen by everyone who has access to your project in svn. The best way to have private comments will be in your notepad.

If you really want to take notes in eclipse while you are coding look at this plugin or you can search for similar other plugins.

[Notepad for eclipse](http://eclipsenotepad.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Using the suggested plugin, is there a way to associate a specific note tab with a specific file (e.g. source file), so I could see the note when I open that source file?

Comment: I don't think so. This is just to take some notes while working in eclipse. Without polluting your works space.